# Nonexistent semicolon

Tags: javascript

```js
alert("There will be an error")
[1, 2].forEach(alert)
```

Now if I run the code, only the first alert is shown and then we have an error! I know why we have an error (no Automatic semicolon insertion) but I don`t understand error message:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined. How JavaScript interpreter read this code?

Comment: I know, my question is : How JavaScript interpreter read this code? Why can JS read property '2' of undefined ?

Comment: [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283)

Comment: It sees your code as `alert("There will be an error")[1, 2].forEach(alert)`, i.e. it's all one statement. The first alert returns undefined, so you have `undefined[1,2].forEach(alert)`. So you're trying to access the `2` property of *undefined*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Answer (score 7):

When you have `<expression>[...]`, the interpreter will attempt to look up a property on `expression`. When the inside of the brackets contains commas, you're invoking the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which evaluates to the value of the last item in the list. So

```
foo[1, 2]
```

is equivalent to

```
foo[2]
```

That's exactly what's happening here:

```js
alert("There will be an error")
[1, 2].forEach(alert)
```

equivalent to

```js
alert("There will be an error")
[2].forEach(alert)
```

equivalent to

```js
alert("There will be an error")[2].forEach(alert)
```

equivalent to (without the `alert` message)

```js
undefined[2].forEach(alert)
```

That's where the "2" comes from. `alert` returns `undefined`, so the error message is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined`.

The `[1, 2]` does *not* get evaluated as an array, even though it kind of looks like one.

Answer (score 0):

If you write JS without semicolons at the end of each line it will sometimes complain if you start a line with:

`[`, `(`, or any of the arithmetic operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.

Explained further here: https://medium.com/@goatslacker/no-you-dont-need-semicolons-148d936b9cf2

So you can avoid this by defining an array as a variable.

```
alert("There will be an error")
var a = [1, 2]
a.forEach(alert)
```

Comment: "*It will complain*" only if the resulting expression causes a syntax or runtime error. It's fairly common to split long statements over multiple lines, often at a dot property accessor (though I'm not a fan of that).